# Error: sequence contains no element recently we upgrade to .NetFramework 4.7.2 t 4.8 version

Tags: c#, collections, enums

I have enums as below

```
public enum CarTypes
 {
    Minicooper= 0,
    ferrari= 1,
    Benz= 2,
    Audi= 4,        
 } 

public ObservableCollection<CarTypes> availableCarList 

public ObservableCollection<CarTypes> AvailableCarList{
 get{
    List<CarTypes> availableList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarTypes))
                    .Cast<CarTypes>()
                    .Where(item =>
                            item == CarTypes.Minicooper ||
                        item == CarTypes.ferrari ||
                            item == CarTypes.Benz ||
                            item == CarTypes.Audi)
                    .ToList();

     availableCarList = new ObservableCollection<CarTypes> 
                                     (availableList);
     return availableCarList;  
   }
 }
public void updatecarslist()
{
    var carList = 
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarTypes)).Cast<availableCarList> 
        ().ToList();

    //which retrives which car's sold same enumtypes only
    var removedOnes = availableCarList.Except(carList).Tolist();
    foreach (var item in removedOnes)
            {
                if (availableCarList .Count > 0)                   
                availableCarList.Remove(item);
            }
        }
  }

previously it works as expected after upgrading 4.8 it giving. Please
```

let me know if anyone have any idea. Thanks for your help in advance

when we try to remove enum item from the list then the issue is coming
like sequence contains no elements but the element is getting deleted
from the observable collection

Comment: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(availableCarList))` does not even compile. It should certainly be `Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarTypes))`.

Comment: `Cast<availableCarList>().` is invalid too.  Generic parameters can only accept types, not fields. And even if the code was `Cast<ObservableCollection<CarTypes>>()`, the expected result is an empty list. There's no way an `object[]` or even `CarTypes[]` can be cast to `ObservableCollection<CarTypes>`

Comment: This code could never work in any .NET Framework version. What is the *actual* code that worked? Was it just `Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarTypes))` perhaps?

Comment: Furthermore, for `availableCarList.Remove(item)` to throw, `availableCarList` would have to be empty. The question's code doesn't load that list anywhere. Where is it created and loaded? Even if the question's code was fixed, `availableCarList` would still be empty, and `Remove` would still fail

Comment: The code i had updated, the issue is if i try to remove any element from observable collection then it is throwing the error but it removes the element from observable collection